# Issues with ar_pose documentation

Tags: jenkins, ar-pose, svn, documentation, ccny-ros-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

It seems like the repository link for ar_pose is wrong. I guess it might have something to do with jenkins... Right now it is associated with the kinton_robot stack, which seems completely wrong. The SVN repository link is also wrong. Does anyone know what's going on [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ar_pose)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54008/issues-with-ar_pose-documentation/) by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1264 on 2013-02-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After posting this on the ros-users mailing list, I was advised by @tfoote to file an issue at the [ros-infrastructure/jenkins_scripts github](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/jenkins_scripts/issues/13) as the metadata for the `ar_pose` package was getting extra information added.

---

Originally posted by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) with karma: 1264 on 2013-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0